# Merging 2 overlapping Area2D nodes?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I have a node called "Merger" which is an `Area2D` with a `CollisionPolygon2D` in it as such:

[image]

with the following script:

```
extends Area2D

onready var shape=$Shape
var is_merging=false


func join(obj): # basically does self shape = overlap_obj shape + self shape
    ...


func merge_in(obj):
    if(is_merging):
        return
    
    if(obj.get_class()==self.get_class()):
        if(obj.is_merging):
            return
        
        is_merging=true
        obj.is_merging=true
        
        join(obj)
        
        is_merging=false
        obj.is_merging=false

        print("deleting=>",obj)
        obj.queue_free()


func _ready():
    self.connect("area_entered",self,"merge_in")
func get_class():
    return "Merger"
```

But whenever I place 2 instance of these on top of each other instead of merging they both get deleted:

[image]

Output on running:

> deleting=>Merger:[Area2D:1269]
> deleting=>Merger2:[Area2D:1272]

Also I'm trying not to use `priority`because setting the priority of every instance would be a pain

I'm trying to make a water like object such that if 2 instance of them overlap they become a singular object,
So is something like this possible? or any similar approach that might *yield* the same results?

Comment: To clarify the behavior, you want them to "stick" to each other? Or for one to disappear and the other to change?

Comment: @Camwin For one to disappear and the other to change

Comment: The areas are freeing each other. Since the entered signals are emitted sequentially the second area's `is_merging` flag is reset to false and continues to call `merge_in`. A fix is to leave the `obj.is_merging` state to true at the end of `merge_in`.

Comment: @hola If the signals are being emitted sequentially shouldn't the signal of the `obj` not be emitted at all since it was queue_freed in the first merger emission? or does `queue_free` wait until all the signals have been emitted before deleting?

Comment: Something like that. It is queuing the free. There is a dedicated queue for this, and Godot will go over it between frames (similar to a deferred call), so it will happen after the signals. Edit: I'm not sure if that applies with a deferred connection, that would be something to test. Edit 2: you can check `is_queued_for_deletion` to know if the other call called `queue_free` on it.

Comment: A further [elaboration](https://godotengine.org/qa/96661/is-there-a-way-to-check-for-recently-freed-object) on what I did, just incase anyone in the future needs it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @hola and @Thearot in the comments I figured it out:

```
extends Area2D

onready var shape=$Shape
var is_merging=false


func join(obj): # Merges object shape into self shape
    ...


func merge_in(obj):
    if(is_merging):
        return
    
    if(obj.get_class()==self.get_class()):
        if(obj.is_merging):
            return
        
        is_merging=true
        obj.is_merging=true
        
        join(obj)
        
        is_merging=false

        print("deleting=>",obj)
        obj.queue_free()


func _ready():
    self.connect("area_entered",self,"merge_in")
func get_class():
    return "Merger"
```

or simply without having a check variable:

```
func merge_in(obj):
    if(self.is_queued_for_deletion()):
        return

    if(obj.get_class()==self.get_class()):
        join(obj)
        obj.queue_free()
```

---

**Edit:**

Turns out the actual "merging" rabbit hole was a bit deeper than I thought
and using `is_merging` variable won't cut it, So I made this small algorithm:

```
var prime:Array=[]

func merge_in(obj:Area2D):
    if(obj.get_class()!=self.get_class()):
        return

    if(self.prime):
        if(obj.prime): # 1 
            if(obj.prime[0]==self.prime[0]):
                return
            
            self.prime[0].join(obj.prime[0])
            obj.prime[0].queue_free()
            obj.prime[0]=self.prime[0]
        else: # 2
            obj.prime=self.prime
            self.prime[0].join(obj)
            obj.queue_free()
    
    else:
        if(obj.prime): # 3
            self.prime=obj.prime
            obj.prime[0].join(self)
            self.queue_free()
        else: # 4
            self.prime=[self]
            obj.prime=self.prime
            self.join(obj)
            obj.queue_free()
```

And this *should* merge any and all overalapping areas:

[image]

Hope this helps ;)